# Logging into app with Networking GET method using JSON

Tags: android, android-networking, android-json

I'm fairly new to Android and some of its core concepts. I'm looking for a basic login screen. In order for the user to login http functions (GET) methods must be used to validate the credentials with the server using JSON object.
The user has 2 login options.

Examiner Login Info:

- Username: admin
- Password: admin

User Login Info:

- Username: user
- Password: 12345

Server: http://mohameom.dev.fast.sheridanc.on.ca/users/verifyUserData.php?name=user&password=12345

Thanks for the help in advance!

How would one go about doing this?

Xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSignin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtUser"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="30dp"
        android:text=""
        android:hint="Username"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edtPass"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="30dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:text=""
        android:hint="Password"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"/>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="30dp"
        android:text="Login"
        android:onClick="loginUser"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. HTTP connection forbidden on default, you should allow it **android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"**

   ```
   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
       android:supportsRtl="true"
       android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
   </activity>
   ```
2. Login Activity (Kotlin, copypast from the documentation -> https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple#kotlin )

   ```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

       setContentView(R.layout.login)

       btnLogin.setOnClickListener {

       val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
       val url =
           "http://mohameom.dev.fast.sheridanc.on.ca/users/verifyUserData.php?name=${edtUser.text}&password=${edtPass.text}"

       val stringRequest = StringRequest(
           Request.Method.GET, url,
           Response.Listener<String> { response ->
               txtSignin.text = response.toString() // Process response if needed
           },
           Response.ErrorListener {
               txtSignin.text = "That didn't work!"
           })
       queue.add(stringRequest)
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Hi, I appreciate you taking the time to help me. However, I'm not familiar with Kotlin, I've been using Java to develop my Android apps. This is however, my fault as I had not specified. If its not too much trouble can you write this code on java, so I can read it? Appreciate all the help!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple#java (SAME THING in JAVA) :)

Comment: this is not only GET request, you should to know, how to add onClickListener to button, read text from EditText fields.... a lot of things you should to know, before starting this simple app

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Retrofit` or `Volley` for API call

Note : Add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`in Manifest for api in http

1. Add Retrofit dependency in Gradle

   ```
   dependencies {
     ...
     implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
     implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
     ...
   }
   ```
2. Create Retrofit Instance class(RetrofitInstance.java)

   ```
   public class RetrofitInstance {

   private static Retrofit retrofit;
   private static String BASE_URL = "http://mohameom.dev.fast.sheridanc.on.ca/";

   /**
    * Create an instance of Retrofit object
    *
    * @param from*/
   public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
       retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
               .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
               .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
               .build();

       return retrofit;
   }
   }
   ```
3. Create interface (GetDataInterface.java)

   ```
   public interface GetDataInterface {
   @GET("users/verifyUserData.php")
   Call<ResponseBody> getLogin(@Query("name") String strUserName, @Query("password") String strPassword);
   }
   ```
4. Now on your Login class

   - Check validation on Button click for Empty & any other validation if needed
   - Check Internet connection
   - if both checks are true then call the Login API method(E.g. callLogin())

     ```
       private void callLogin() {
       //open progress
       GetDataInterface service = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(GetDataInterface.class);
       Call<ResponseBody> call = service.getLogin(strUserName, strPassword);
       call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
       try{
          JSONObject resultObj = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
          String strIsValid = resultObj.getString("login");
         //dismiss progress
         //check the condition and direct to next screen(your flow)
         }catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
       }
       @Override
       public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
         //dismiss progress
       }
       }
     ```